# FPDF issue while generating pdf with images

Tags: php, fpdf

```
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf->AddPage("P", "A4"); 
$pdf->SetDisplayMode(150,'default');

$pdf->Image($imagepath,60,30,90,0,'JPG');

b_end_clean();
$pdf->Output();
```

('FPDF error: Not a JPEG file: https://myurl.com')

Comment: what is kept at `$imagepath`

Comment: image path : https//www.website.com/images/imagename.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use the image from local folder that is always best.
For this kind of error only one suggestion even though it have the extension of jpeg clearly they are not jpeg image.Me also face the same problem. Just download one jpg image from google and try this code sure it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading it in your image editor and saving it again.
I had the same issue and happened because I only renamed the file.